# Is a pressurized tank required for reverse osmosis systems?

Tags: osmosis

It seems that a pressurized tank solves a few problems:

a) Where to store the water
b) How to get the water from a low point to a high point (floor to sink).
c) How to provide water pressure after the R/O system, as the filtration system limits the household incoming pressure.

I am interested in building a much larger elevated tank which would be a reservoir for filtered water with a simple valve at the bottom of the tank.

This would render the automatic pressure controlled shutoff valve obsolete.  In lieu of that valve, there would be an electronic valve controlled by a microprocessor which would be tied to an ultrasonic sensor in the upper tank which would not only serve as a trigger to control the valve, but would also measure the volume, recording water usage.

**QUESTION:**

Does the pressurized tank do anything more than provide pressure after the filter and  a means by which to stop water filtration when the tank is full?

Answer (score 0):

The tank is just storage.  The pressurization is simply to provide water pressure to the faucet when the faucet gets opened.  Storing the tank above the faucet would serve the same purpose, although performance may be anemic.  It's much easier to get the pressures you need from... pressure... rather than just using gravitation. You may need to add a pump to get the performance you need.

As an aside, I would recommend shying away from re-inventing the wheel with the auto-shutoff.  A failure which left it open would waste a remarkable amount of water.  In general, I find we shy away from complex electronics in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why a reverse osmosis system works to purify water is that a high pressure P is required to force the pure water molecules through the RO membrane. Those water molecules are collected at a lower pressure -P than initial pressure P. If you want to raise the pure water from its collection point, a pump must be used.

```
      Water pressure P ---------RO system ----------Reject flow to drain
                                    |
                           Collection tank -P
```

Comment: Yes, I get that.  But that pressure is provided by the city.  The tank's pressure is purely to push the water to the faucet for consumption, which could easily be gravity fed, provided there's enough mass in the overhead tank to supply ample pressure.